# Json.Encode(Model) throws "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, razor

I have a simple razor view:

```
<script>var fieldList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));</script>
```

This line throws `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed` exception. If I remove it all works fine even when I use `Model` later in View.

```
foreach (SomeCustomObject pField in Model)
{
    <div>
        @pField.SomeProperty
    </div>
}
```

Controller action

```
    ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    List<SomeCustomObject> tList = new List<SomeCustomObject>();
    using(EFEntities db = new EFEntities())
    {
        tList = db.SomeCustomObject.ToList();
    }
    return View(tList);
}
```

I presume, that it could be because object has navigation properties that no longer work. Is it possible to tell `Json.Encode` to use only NON navigation preperties of object?

Comment: Please, provide code of your controller class

Answer (score 1):

You can't operate on model obejct outside of `using` block, where it is loaded. Possibly, `JSON.encode` does deep reflection analysis of model object and so touches some context-dependent attributes.

So, in common case, you should convert model to JSON in **controller/action** method, **inside `using` block**, put it to string variable and then use this variable in template.

Comment: As You confirmed - problem realy was with relations, so I used a bit different aproach - I hope it does that I think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way that I came up with was:

1. Create view ViewSomeCustomObjects in database, what returns all fields of SomeCustomObjects table.
2. Update model from database and include new view.
3. Use entity what is maped to view instead of table, as this is only for data display.
4. I REALY hope that if I change SomeCustomObjects table in database, changes will cascade trough entire solution...

Answer (score 0):

Disable lazy loading on the context first with **`context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`** before you start pulling stuff out of your database.

```
using (var context = new SomeEntityContext())
{
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // This is the fixer.
   return context.SomeEntitiesWithRelations.ToList();
}
```